# How to show minio monitoring logs

Tags: file, logging, minio

I want to know how to open the monitoring logs on the page provided by Minio.

so i want to be able to view the monitoring log information in MiniO, record and view the log information such as file upload and file deletion. I click the Start Log button in the monitoring log menu, but there is no log record of my uploading, downloading and deleting files.

What other steps do I need to take to view the logs of file upload and file deletion in the menu of the monitoring log, and what logs are recorded in the monitoring log, because it is always without any records.

If you provide the answer, I will be extremely grateful.

In the minio monitoring log, there is no record of my operation on the file, nor is there any content displayed.

I tried the mc admin logs command of minio client.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnCA2.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Audit logs based on your need to monitor bucket/file operations. You can configure webhook to start collecting audit logs as mentioned [here](https://min.io/docs/minio/windows/operations/monitoring/minio-logging.html#minio-logging-publish-audit-logs)